# Android Studio 3.2 Canary 14: The following packages are not available "Package id platforms;android-28"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

Just installed new Android Studio 3.2 Canary 14 build with *clean config* to try out new AndroidX. After creating new project going to **Refactor -> Refactor to AndroidX** and Studio asks to upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to **28**. Doing the upgrade in *build.gradle* got *Install missing platform tools* and then error: **The following packages are not available "Package id platforms;android-28"** SDK Manager says that Platform P is partially installed (no source-code package). Update channel set to Canary, tried to completely redownload SDK - did not help. Using Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.4

Here is *build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Here is my SDK Manager window:
[SDK Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKefy.png)

Here is my Android Studio build info: [Update channel and AS build Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT6s2.png)

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fully test your app's compatibility with Android P and begin using new APIs, open your module-level build.gradle file and update the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion as shown here:

```
android {
    // sdk version 28
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P' 

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 'P'
    }
    ...
}
```

Please read [Set Up the Android P SDK](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk) for further information

Comment: That helped, thank you! Also should be `minSdkVersion 'P'`

Comment: in case you want to support devices version android P and above @Imajou. For more about version distribution, take a look at this https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards